# Uploading image fails MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-first

Hello StackOverflow Community.
I have problem with image uploads in my project of MVC (code-first) database.

I can upload images and the codepaths to the database with success.
Altough, editing those values returns me a null.

This is my Create Controller which sucessfully uploads images

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IDProduto,Nome,Descricao,Preco,IVA,Fotografia,Peso,Stock,Active,CategoriaFK")] Produto produto, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string FullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Imagens_Produto/") + FileName;
                    file.SaveAs(FullPath);
                    produto.Fotografia = FileName;
                }

                db.Produtos.Add(produto);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.CategoriaFK = new SelectList(db.Categoria, "CategoriaID", "Nome", produto.CategoriaFK);
            return View(produto);
        }
```

And this is my EDIT which fails to change my image and returns a null point exception.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "IDProduto,Nome,Descricao,Preco,IVA,Fotografia,Peso,Stock,Active,CategoriaFK")] Produto produto, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string FullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Imagens_Produto/") + FileName;
                file.SaveAs(FullPath);
                produto.Fotografia = FileName;

                db.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.CategoriaFK = new SelectList(db.Categoria, "CategoriaID", "Nome", produto.CategoriaFK);
            return View(produto);
        }
```

And this is the field that I have on my both Create and Edit Views

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fotografia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input id="Fotografia" title="Upload de imagem" type="file" name="file" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

your entity not loaded from DB and you should use 'Attach' method before 'Entry' method

```
 db.Produtos.Attach(produto);
 db.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();
```